# php5-fpm does not initialize after ubuntu 12.04 reboot

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm

When I reboot my Ubuntu 12.04, php5-fpm doesn't run automatically.
However nginx does start automatically.

I am using Unix socket instead of TCP\IP

This is the output of `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm status` after a server reboot:

/etc/init.d/php5-fpm status
 * php5-fpm is not running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried update-rc.d?

When you execute `sudo update-rc.d php5-fpm defaults` php5-fpm wil start at boot.

Comment: It fixed it, thanks. But can you please tell me what does update-rc do?